# How to prevent MouseDown event on a child control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have nested grids

```
 <Grid x:Name="Grid1"  MouseDown="Grid2_MouseUp">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want `MouseDown` event raise only when clicking on `Grid1`.

How to prevent `MouseDown` from raising when `Grid2` is clicked?

Comment: Do they have the same size or is `Grid2` occupying only a portion of `Grid1`?

Comment: Grid2 is inside Grid1.

Comment: That's not the question: do they have the same size? Is it possible to differentiate a click on Grid2 from a click on Grid1 in the first place?

Comment: Yes Grid2 Takes only a portion of Grid1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose You can just add a `MouseDown` event handling method to `Grid2` and in the method only set `e.Handled` to `true`.

So, the code of the `MouseDown` associated with `Grid2` can look like this:

```
void Grid2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Setting `Handled` property to `true` should prevent the event to be invoked for other controls.

Please refer to *Remarks* section in MSDN documentation of the `Handled` property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx